# Overloading constructor Params

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor-overloading

Consider:

```
class MyList<T> {
  public MyList(params T[] ts) { /* add all items to internal list */ }
  public MyList(params IEnumerable<T>[] ets) { /* add all items from all enumerables to internal list */ }
}
```

And then

```
record Employee(string Name, int Age);

var l1 = new MyList<int>(1, 2, 3); // ok

IEnumerable<Employee> e = new List<Employee>() { new("John", 30), new("Eric", 30) };
var l2 = new MyList<Employee>(e, e); // ok

var l3 = new MyList<Employee>(
  new("John", 30),
  new("Eric", 30)
);
```

For `l3` I get:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `MyList<T>.MyList(params T[])` and `MyList<T>.MyList(params IEnumerable<T>[])`

I don't understand why `l1` compiles and `l3` does not?

Is there a way to make all 3 work?

Comment: All samples compiles successfully in .NET 5

Comment: @Fabio Really? Didn't work for me though, and my `dotnet --version` is 5.0.103.

Comment: @Fabio really ? strange .. I'm on latest VSD19 preview .NET 6

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/plS6qp

Comment: something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933632/passing-array-to-function-that-takes-either-params-object-or-ienumerablet/39154090)

Comment: Ah seems like the difference is that you use `new Employee(` and I use `new(`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with how target-typed `new` works. From the [proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new), it has the following feature:

> A target_typed_new expression does not have a type. However, there is a new object creation conversion that is an implicit conversion from expression, that exists from a target_typed_new to every type.

During overload resolution of `MyList`'s constructors, it looks at `new("John", 30)` and `new("Eric", 30)` and finds that there are conversions from those expressions, to both `Employee` and `IEnumerable<Employee>`, so both overloads are applicable, and neither is better. Hence the call is ambiguous.

In that sense, it's a bit like the `null` literal, or the `default` literal, and I suspect that `l3` doesn't work because of a similar reason that this doesn't work:

```
var l3 = new MyList<Employee>(
    default,
    default
);
```

Though, the documentation also says:

> The following are consequences of the specification:
>
> - ...
> - The following kinds of types are not permitted as targets of the conversion
>
>   - ...
>   - Interface types: This would work the same as the corresponding creation expression for COM types.
>   - ...

and `IEnumerable<Employee>` is an interface.

Which suggests that the "whether the conversion is valid" is done after overload resolution, which is weird. But the fact that interfaces are invalid targets is only a "consequence" of the spec, and not explicitly specified (the conversion is specified to be valid *to all types*, but since *target-typed new* is a kind of *object creation expressions*, and you can't use interfaces in *object creation expressions*), so I guess it's technically fine.

Comment: but `new("John", 30)` is definitely not an 'IEnumerable<T>' (or any IEnumerable for that matter as it has different types) why or as what is it considered ?

Comment: @kofifus During overload resolution, the compiler only looks at the available conversions the argument expressions has to the parameter types of the overloads. From the quote, conversions "exist from a target_typed_new to every type", so during overload resolution, the compiler thinks `new("John", 30)` can be converted to `IEnumerable<T>`, and if overload resolution succeeds, it will _later_ find out that that won't work.