# Difference between new() and new class() C#

Tags: c#, class, object, methods

What is the difference between new() and new class() because it seems that both run with no difference.

```
Human John = new();
```

or

```
Human John = new Human();
```

Let's say in this context it does not make any difference, could anyone provide an example of which both cases would result in different outputs for each code. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, it won't yield different results, they are the same, it is just a syntactic sugar. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#target-typed-new)

Comment: [New operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator) (Target-typed - C# 9)

Comment: _"could anyone provide an example of which both cases would result in different outputs for each code"_ - it's not quite a "difference", but neither of these examples will compile: `var x = new();` and `ISomeInterface x = new()`.

Comment: Adding to Dai's comment, basically you can't use `new()` if the compiler can't figure out what type to instantiate. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68232880/5133585), which shows another such situation.

Comment: It's syntactic sugar: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTuApgB4CGAtgA4A2LdAF50AOxYB3OgG5GRAL5z0StJgoA5OgyRNm6dt36CR4iThlLFSeUA=

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You ask about the difference between `new()` and `new class()`. It is unclear what `class` is referring to. *Which class?*

If it can be any class, then a trivial situation where `new()` and `new class()` would produce different outputs is when `class` is a derived class of the type you are assigning it to. `object x = new();` would create an instance of `object`, and `object x = new StringBuilder();` would create a new `StringBuilder`.

If you mean `class` must be the same as the type that you are assigning to, then a situation where `new()` and `new class()` would produce different outputs is when you are assigning to a nullable type.

```
int? x = new(); // same as int? x = 0;
int? x = new int?(); // same as int? x = null;
```

Because the target type in this case is the non-nullable `int` type.

Also note that sometimes the type you are assigning to cannot be instantiated with the syntax `new class()` - such as when it is an interface, abstract class, array type, etc. In these cases, `new()` also won't work.

There are also situations where `new()` just won't compile, but `new class()` would, for some `class`. e.g. `var x = new();`, `SomeGenericMethod(new())` where `SomeGenericMethod` needs the type of the first parameter to infer a type parameter. These don't work because the compiler can't figure out what type `new()` should instantiate. See also an interesting case in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68232880/5133585).

Learn more about `new()`, aka target-typed `new` expression, in the [draft spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new#specification).

Comment: You can instantiate a tuple type with `new` using both `new ValueTuple<...>` and target-typed `new`: https://sharplab.io/#gist:decee6f132b1b8149e00c2a4b27e0ec8

Comment: Also, "cannot be instantiated with the syntax `new class()` - such as (...) array type (...) in these cases, `new()` also won't work."

You can instantiate arrays with target-typed `new`, so this is inaccurate.

Comment: @V0ldek do you mean `new[]`? That is a different kind of expression, and not what this question is about. `int[] x = new();` certainly does not compile.

Comment: okay, you're right, that's a different feature from target-typed. For `int[] x = new()` it does explicitly give CS8752, The type 'int[]' may not be used as the target type of `new()`.

Which makes sense I guess, there's no way for it to know the size.

Comment: @V0ldek The tuple case is interesting. I didn’t expect that, since the draft spec says tuples are not allowed as target types. Perhaps it got changed later.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. The first snipped uses [target-typed `new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#target-typed-new), which allows you to omit the name of the class if it's known.

Known basically means that it can be unambiguously inferred from the type of the left-hand-side. In this case, you explicitly wrote `Human John`, so the compiler automatically infers you wanted to create an instance of `Human`.

The entire purpose behind this, however, is to make no difference. The behaviour should never be surprising. This is just shorter syntax with not functional differences.