# Can IEnumerable be an alternative to Params[]?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, parameters

Can IEnumerable be a possible alternative to params[]?

Because Ive been hearing some articles that params is not good, but I seem to doubt it because it is syntactically straightforward and is very useful.

ex.

```
public void testMeth(IEnumerable<object> testerEnum){
    //Code here
}
```

Comment: There is a difference. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580277/why-use-the-params-keyword

Comment: Do your really need to test meth you got? :) I just love how you can cut some words...

Comment: Hahaha, just for the fun of it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the params keyword importantly allows callers of your method not to wrap the arguments into a collection at all.

With:

```
public bool testMeth(params object[] input){
    // ... things
    return purity >= REQUIRED_PURITY; //this is how to test meth, right?
}
```

The caller can call

```
var is_good = testMeth("apples", new object(), 7);
```

with no need to make their own array.

Comment: This is an excellent, and practical, interpretation of the OP's business logic. +1

Comment: We can't always be serious. Sometimes you just have take the opportunities to be a little silly.