# How to ignore if var is null c#

Tags: c#

I'm joining a load of strings to make a superstring but i need to ignore a param if one is null. Currently i cannot think how to do this other than emcompassing all the params in seperate if statements. Help pls:

Here the code

```
 public void LinkBuilder(string baselink, string sharedkey, string service, string period, string bulletintype,
        string includeresults, string includemap, string username, string password)
    {
        sharedkey = "&" + sharedkey;
        service = "&" + service;
        period = "&" + period;
        bulletintype = "&" + bulletintype;
        includeresults = "&" + includeresults;
        includemap = "&" + includemap;
        username= "&" + username;
        password = "&" + password;

        string completeLink = sharedkey + service + period + bulletintype + includeresults + includemap + username +
                              password;
```

Not sure how to tackle this.

Comment: forgot to include baselink in completeLink. Doesn't really matter, but i thought I'd point it out before someone else does.

Comment: Aside from anything else, are you sure you don't need to URL-encode the parameters? And do you *really* want to put a password in a URL?

Comment: Are you talking about `public void Sample(string key, string service = null)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet - its just for internal testing use. It will not be publically available.

Comment: you need to skip the param, if the value is null right?

Comment: What is a "Superstring" ?

Comment: Superstring is combination of smaller strings

Comment: @Greg - Lets say is sharedkey was null, I do not want it to be overridden with the "&" + sharedkey; or not to be included in the complete link, however since i am overriding sharedkey it will never be null when it gets to "string completeLink",

Comment: Yes @Arvaan. lol exactly seth

Comment: @Kam It sure looks like you're trying to create a url. Are you trying to assemble a query string? If so, you're going about things the wrong way...

Comment: @Seth Kitchen, and if I combine Superstrings, will I get a Hyperstring?

Comment: Yes and Two Hyperstrings = EPIC string

Comment: I think if you combine two or more epic strings, a kitten will die, or a black hole will be created, who knows.

Comment: No, if you combine two epicstrings, you would get a ....  sorry, this is GiliusMaximus' wife.  He will not be able to continue his post.  His brain just exploded.

Comment: @GiliusMaximus hahah you guys!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would really refactor it this way:

```
public void LinkBuilder(params string[] links)
{
    string completeLink = String.Join("&", links.Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
}
```

Comment: Possibly make it a `params` parameter, so the caller doesn't even need to create the array...

Comment: for easy use you could add the params keyword public void LinkBuilder(params string[] links) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580277/why-use-the-params-keyword)

Comment: ok , i think this is the winner, but I would add the params keyword to the method arguments - public void LinkBuilder(params string[] links) -  so that the user can still call it with a number of strings separated by commas - LinkBuilder(mybaselink, mysharedkey, myservice...) - but the method accepts them as a string array.

Comment: Also the question didn't request that empty strings should be ignored

Comment: @Stumblor - but it seems like that would be assumed unless otherwise stated, if null is ignored, empties also.

Comment: You also might want to add an "&" at the beginning of the string, since String.join will only put the separator between the strings, and the OP seemed to want one from the beginning.

Comment: @GiliusMaximus would this ensure the strings are in order?

Comment: Also sorry to be such a noob, how would i call the LinkBuilder method? LinkBuilder(string baselink, string sharedkey, string service) and it will automatically put the passed param in the array?

Comment: the same as you did it before

Comment: @Kam - yes, the "where" LINQ operation preserves order.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/204777/4843530

Comment: It worked - this was my output. "http: //xx.aspx?&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x" which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks guys

Comment: @Kam Seems like a problem, I mean you have `?&x` you have a giant key with no value, and you the `?&` doesn't seem value.

Comment: @Greg Nope it works, I have replaced the values. the base link is "...blah.aspx?"

Answer (score 1):

You can do a check of strings by operator ?: in method.

```
public void LinkBuilder(string baselink, string sharedkey, string service, string period, string bulletintype,
        string includeresults, string includemap, string username, string password)
    {
        sharedkey = checkValue(sharedkey);
        service = checkValue(service );
        period = checkValue(period );
        bulletintype = checkValue(bulletintype );
        includeresults = checkValue(includeresults );
        includemap = checkValue(includemap );
        username= checkValue(username );
        password = checkValue(password );

        string completeLink = sharedkey + service + period + bulletintype + includeresults + includemap + username +
                              password;
}
private String checkValue(String str)
{
    return str != null ? "&" + str : "";
}
```

Comment: This will add all the '&'s to the string though

Comment: use string.IsNullOrEmpty before doing the assignment instead i.e: sharedKey = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedKey) ? string.Empty :"&" + sharedKey

Answer (score 1):

Make an enumerable collection of your strings, use a bit of linq to filter out the nulls, then join it all back together again with `String.Join`:

```
var elements = 
    new[]{baselink, sharedkey, service, period, 
          bulletintype, includeresults, includemap, 
          username, password};
var nonNullElements = elements.Where(e => e != null);
var outputString = String.Join("&", nonNullElements);
```

On the off-chance that you're actually trying to assemble a querystring, there are better ways.

For instance, you could leverage `HttpUtility` and reflection using the following method for parsing an anonymous object to a query string:

```
public static class ObjEx
{
    public static string ToQueryString(this object data)
    {
        var collection = data.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Aggregate(
                HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty),
                (prev,curr) => {
                    var val = curr.GetValue(data);
                    var propName = curr.Name;
                    prev.Add(propName,val.ToString());
                    return prev;
            });
        return collection.ToString();
    }
}
```

then

```
var data = new{foo = "bar", num = 1, cat = "bad", dog = "good", needsEscaping = "é\"&"};
Console.WriteLine(data.ToQueryString());
```

will give you:

```
foo=bar&num=1&cat=bad&dog=good&needsEscaping=%u00e9%22%26
```

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is to avoid wrapping each parameter in an if statement, you could add them to a list, then use `String.Join`, and `Linq.Select`

```
        public void LinkBuilder(string baselink, string sharedkey, string service, string period, string bulletintype,
            string includeresults, string includemap, string username, string password)
    {
        var allParams = new List<string>
        {
            baselink,
            sharedkey,
            service,
            period,
            bulletintype,
            includeresults,
            includemap,
            username,
            password
        };

        var completeLink = "?" + String.Join("&", allParams.Select(p => p != null));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below would accept a `Collection` which I feel may be better maintainable.  I re factored a bit.

```
public string LinkBuilder(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
     var url = String.Empty;
     foreach(var parameter in parameters)
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Value))
               url += String.Format("&{0}={1}", parameter.Key, parameter.Value);

     return url;
}
```

This way you would pass a collection to build your URL, then it would `return` the giant URL for you.  You have a massive selection, I personally like Maksim's answer.