# Using one method for multiple scenarios

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a web app using Asp.net webforms. The requirement is to populate a gridview based on selected value from dropdown which I can achieve no problem. What I'm trying to do is minimize my code so I don't have to repeat myself. So I've created a method which returns a `DataTable` from the query that is passed in as a parameter to that function.

```
public DataTable GetData(string Query)
{
 //Do stuff i.e. sql reader 
  ...
}
```

Some of the Sql quesries will have params and others won't e.g.

1. `SELECT TESTONE FROM MY TABLE WHERE TESTONE = @param`
2. `SELECT TESTTWO FROM MY TABLE`

I want to be able to call `GetData()` method with both of the above queries but I can't figure out how to extend my function to accommodate for both scenarios. If someone can guide me I would highly appreciate it.

Would using a `GetData(string Query, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)` be a overkill in this case?

Comment: No, a `Dictionary<string, object> parameters` would not be overkill . You might even find a [`List<SqlParameter>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) to be even better

Comment: @Rhumborl If I use `Dictionary<string, object> parameters` how would I call my method for the first query? or would it be possible if you can provide a short example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out by making the following changes to the my code.

```
public DataTable GetTrainingData(string query, params string[] parameters)
{
 // Do work here
}
```

I can now call the same method for both of my queries as

1. `GetTrainingData("SqlQuery")`
2. `GetTrainingData("SqlQuery", parameters)`

Further reading on `params` key word **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580277/why-use-the-params-keyword)**