# Why can Task.WhenAll take any number of Task arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

While reviewing Async and Await, I noticed that Task.WhenAll could be called with any number of parameters:

```
Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(New Threading.Tasks.Task(New Action(Sub() Console.WriteLine("Hello"))),
                             New Threading.Tasks.Task(New Action(Sub() Console.WriteLine("Hello"))),
                             New Threading.Tasks.Task(New Action(Sub() Console.WriteLine("Hello"))),
                             New Threading.Tasks.Task(New Action(Sub() Console.WriteLine("Hello"))),
                             New Threading.Tasks.Task(New Action(Sub() Console.WriteLine("Hello"))))
```

Why does this work, but methods like Array.Reverse do not allow you to pass any number of parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use the params keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580277/why-use-the-params-keyword)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that after looking at the code on the [.Net Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com) site, specifically [the overload with an array of Tasks](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,929d1a3d98d89901), and after looking at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580277/why-use-the-params-keyword), I found that the **params** keyword ([ParamArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/538f81ec.aspx) in VB.Net) allows you to pass no arguments, any number of comma separated arguments of the specified type, or an array of the specified type.

You can think of it like destructuring an Array in Javascript or the args array in Python.

Comment: This looks like JS `...theArgs` to me: String [from metadata] ... `public static string Format(string format, params object[] args);`

Comment: This also applies to methods such as `Path.Combine` from the `System.IO` namespace, you'll come across this often.

Comment: As a rule, when in doubt, right-click on any .NET method or class in VS and select "Go to Definition". Careful with `params object[]` though, when you define your own: You can get unexpected results with overloads.