# How to call function with List in head

Tags: c#, .net, list, parameters

I want to send along several integers with my function through a list like this:

```
public string createCompleteJump(List<int>kID)
```

kID is they key ID which is connected to several dictionaries hence why it is important to select different integers.

function:

```
public string createCompleteJump(List<int>kID)
{
    // List<int> kID = new List<int>(); // Key ID
    double vID = 3; // Value ID
    string v2ID = "Framåt";
    var myKey = qtyScrews[kID[0]].FirstOrDefault(y => y == vID);
    var myKey2 = qtyFlips[kID[1]];
    var myKey3 = jumpCombination[kID[2]].FirstOrDefault(y => y == v2ID);
    var myKey4 = jumpHeight[kID[3]];
    var myKey5 = startPos[kID[4]];

    var str = $"{myKey}{myKey2}{myKey3}{myKey4}{myKey5}";
    Console.Write("\nCompleteJump:" + str);
    return str;
}
```

How would I send along 5 arguments when calling the function through a list?
Eg:

```
public string createCompleteJump(3,4,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use the params keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580277/why-use-the-params-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `params` keyword:

```
public string createCompleteJump(params int[] kID)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w5zay9db.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You either need to *create* a list to pass as argument:

```
createCompleteJump(new List<int> {3,4,2,3,4});
```

or you could change your method to accept an undefined number of arguments:

```
public string createCompleteJump(params int[] kID)
{ /* ... */ }
```

The [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) key word states that there can be an arbitrary number of `int` and that they are combined into an array:

```
createCompleteJump(3,4,2,3,4);
```

results in an `int[]` array containing the specified values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use params or you can instantiate your list to be sent to your function, like this:

```
List<int> keyIDList = new List<int> {3,4,2,3,4};
createCompleteJump(keyIDList)
```