# Setting values to private data via constructor

Tags: c#

This is what I have tried so far:

```
class Student 
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && value != "") // if empty, no go
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }          
    }
```

Now I need to add a list of names there i.e "Jake, Bolt, House, Doe"

I have attempted

```
Student n = new Student(Jake, Bolt, House, Doe); // no good.
```

1st week learning programming.
Advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need a list or array of `Student`. Have you studied those yet?

Comment: You need to create multiple `Student` objects, each one with a different name.

Comment: Quick side note, `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` exists.  use that

Comment: Learn about constructors in your programming text.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `new` syntax, you are essentially calling a special method called a constructor. A constructor always has the same name as the class and never has a return type (not even void). Otherwise, you write it like an ordinary method (with certain enhanced abilities). So for example

```
class Student
{
    public Student(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

If you then instantiate a Student, the constructor runs:

```
var s = new Student("Joe");  //Outputs "Joe"
```

If you would like to accept two names, you could of course add a constructor with two arguments:

```
class Student
{
    public Student(string name1, string name2)
    {
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

Or if you want a flexible number of arguments, you can use the [params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580277/why-use-the-params-keyword) keyword:

```
class Student
{
    public Student(params string[] name)
    {
        //Implementation
    }
}
```

Although it looks like an array to the constructor, the caller can supply a list of arguments as if they were separate parameters. The compiler will convert the parameter list into an array.

```
var s = new Student("John","Dick","Harry");
```

On the other hand, this whole approach doesn't make sense to me. A student has only one name. Maybe you need a list of students, like this:

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Student(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

var s = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Student>();
s.Add(new Student("John"));
s.Add(new Student("Dick"));
s.Add(new Student("Harry"));
```

Here is a [link to a working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hcsdCf)

Comment: While most of this answer is fine, I wouldn't recommend creating a special collection class just for the sake of it - just use `List<Student>` instead of creating a `StudentList` class.

Comment: Tried this but its saying "the contextual keyword "var" may only appear within a local variable declaration..."

Comment: I'll add a link to a working example so you can see how it all fits together.

Comment: Thanks John !, Worked Great

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you need to pass the student name to the constructor, you need to create a constructor that accepts a string parameter so you can use it to set the name of the student (it doesn't work automatically):

```
class Student 
{
    public Student(string stName)
    {
        Name = stName;
    }

    // Rest of your class.
    // .
}
```

Now, you can create students like this:

```
Student st1 = new Student("Jake");   // Note that the name needs to be enclosed in double
Student st2 = new Student("Bolt");   // quotes ("someName") because it's a string literal.
```

This will create two `Student` objects that you can add to a `List<Student>`:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.Add(st1);
students.Add(st2);
```

Now, that you get the idea, you can also create a static method in the `Student` class which takes multiple student names as parameters using the [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword, creates the students for you and returns a `List<Student>` like this:

```
class Student
{
    public static List<Student> CreateStudents(params string[] names)
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        foreach (string stName in names)
        {
            students.Add(new Student(stName));
        }
        return students;
    }

    // Rest of your class.
    // .
}
```

Which you can call like this:

```
List<Student> students = Student.CreateStudents("Jake", "Bolt", "House", "Doe");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    ....
    var jake = new Student("Jake");
    var bolt = new Student("Bolt");
    var house = new Student("House");
    var doe = new Student("Doe");
}

public class Student 
{
    public Student(String name) { Name = name; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

You don't need anything inside the property setter unless you are trying to leave the previously set name if no value is set which would be a strange requirement.

Comment: This does not prevent `Name` from being set if the string is not null or empty which the OP's logic currently has

Comment: var s = new Student(); s.Name = "Hello"; s.Name = null; Clearly using his code the result would be Console.Write(s.Name ); // Outputs Hello. I never claimed that Name would be prevented from being set if it was non-null

Answer (score 0):

If this is the Student class, so I would say that you will need to create multiple Students with different names.

Something like that:

```
Student s1 = new Student("Joe");
Student s2 = new Student("Mark");
Student s3 = new Student("Gegee");
```

And then you can add these Student to a list to be available for future use, something like:

```
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>{
s1, s2, s3
};
```

But for sure in this case you will need to implement the constructor in the `Student` class:

```
class Student{
  public Student(string name)
  { this.name = name; }
}
```

And also you can use your Property `Name` to set the `Student` name instead of the constructor:

```
Student s1 = new Student();
s1.Name = "Joe";
```

In case you want this Student class to hold multiple students, I would suggest call it something like `Class` or `Group` and this class will contain multiple student objects or list of students names.